# How to formulate the inequality constraint $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z$ using gurobipy?

Tags: python, gurobi, convex-optimization, disciplined-convex-programming, socp

How to formulate the following constraint using gurobipy

$$ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le z$$

where  $x, y, z$ are continuous optimization variables?

---

I saw how to formulate it using CVXPY:

```py
cp.norm(cp.hstack([x, y])) <= z
```

I am now wondering how to formulate it in gurobipy. I did not find any information on how to formulate the norm convex function in the gurobipy documentation.

If take the square of both sides,

$$ x^2 + y^2 \le z^2 $$

gurobipy solves it but doesn't this constraint violate DCP rules? I thought the constraint will be following the DCP rules if convex $\leq$ constant, convex $\leq$ concave, but here it is convex $\leq$ convex.

Comment: $x^2+y^2\le z^2, z\ge 0$ is recognized by Gurobi as a second-order cone. That is a convex constraint.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Erwin Kalvelagen. Gurobi accepts this constraint, but I was concerned about what follows: $ x^2+y^2$  is convex, and $ z^2 $ is another convex function. I know that convex<= convex is not a disciplined convex problem. Thanks!

Comment: Just think of it as an input format of a conic constraint.

Comment: I guess gurobi will handle this as quadratic constraints: z^2 is linearized by McCormick envelope; in that case: x^2+^2<= linear is a convex constraint. Thanks again to @ Erwin Kalvelagen

Comment: No, it is recognized as a 2nd order cone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the Gurobi staff, this is how to formulate it using the norm constraint:

```py
import gurobipy as gp
m=gp.Model()
m.addGenConstrNorm(aux, [x, y], 2, "normconstr")
m.addConstr(aux<=z)
```

Ref: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10762215603345-SOCP

Comment: Congrats! Does it appear in any of their documentation/manual? It used to appear then I myself wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Thank you! You can the following: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10762215603345-SOCP